# Uploading a file with YUI3 to a RESTful PUT url

Tags: file, rest, upload, yui3, put

I'm trying to upload a file to a RESTful PUT url with YUI3, but when I set upload to true in the config to io it sends the file as POST not PUT. If I remove the upload setting in the config I just get the filename, but it does go to the PUT url. Can I use PUT with a file upload? Is there another way to do this?
I'm assuming this is a failure/fault in YUI3 or rather my use of it.

```
Form:
<form id='GFileForm' method='PUT' onSubmit='return false;'>
<input type='file' name='gfile' id='GFileName'>
<input type='submit' name='gfileupload' value='Upload' id='GFileUpload_Button'>
</form>

JS:
var cfg = {
                        method: "PUT",
                        form: {id: 'GFileForm', upload: true},
                        content_type: "multipart/form-data",
                };

var request = Y.io(sUrl, cfg);
```

Any help is here much appreciated.

I've also tried to find a resource on reading the file contents with javascript and then pushing that into the PUT data, but I can't seem to find anything about that. Does anyone know if that's a possiblilty?

Cheers,
Andy.

Answer (score 1):

PUT is not a [standard way](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-format) of sending form data and most web browsers don't support it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. https://github.com/chmouel/cors-swift-example

In this example, you can see how we can PUT files to RESTful PUT url.